# How to create a video file using multiple video files?

Tags: java, android, video, sdk

I want to merge/join multiple (around 8-20 small video file, mp4 format) in to one video file.

While researching on it, I only get one library for this [MP4Parser](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mp4parser/wikis/AppendTracks.wiki).

This tool is helpful in merging two video files. But in my case I did not find it useful.

If anyone know any better solution for this, please help me. I really stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is perfect for this.

If you would like to concatenate (join) all `.mp4` files in a directory, for example, you could do the following:

**1) Generate a list of video files**

```
for f in ./*.mp4; do echo "file '$f'" >> mylist.txt; done
```

**2) Concatenate all videos in that list**

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output
```

You can read more about [concatenation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)  in the docs.

Comment: I tried lots of FFmpeg example from web, but that was not helpful, Finally I complete my work with MP4Parser, I found way to parse multiple video by MP4Parser. But Your code is looking very cool. I will try it surely and if it work i accept your answer.